# Understanding CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

According to the Apple's docs, when calling `CBPeripheralManager`'s `-startAdvertising:` method, there's the optional key `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey` which states the following:

> Any service universally unique identifiers (UUIDs) contained in the
>   value of the CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey key that do not fit in
>   the allotted space are added to a special “overflow” area; they can be
>   discovered only by an iOS device that is explicitly scanning for them.

What's this overflow area and how large is it? How many UUIDs can I fit there? On top of that, does this overflow area only work on iOS or is it from the BLE specs? As they put it

> they can be discovered **only by an iOS** device that is explicitly scanning for them